# Using API to update value in another python program

Tags: python, flask

I am currently building a raspberry pi project to monitor the surrounding temperature and buzz if it’s too high. The program is simple it reads the config (temp to buzz at) from a file and it uses it for the infinite while loop. I was thinking of making a separate program for a flask server to act as a GUI and the user can change the config value. I thought of making a endpoint e.g. /update so I can send the new data to it and the flask server will write it into the config file.

The problem is that I am unsure how can I make the program that is reading the temperature and in the infinite loop take in the new config value. I was thinking of simply using code and restart the program so that it can re-read the config file with the new value and run again but I am unsure if there is a better solution. Any ideas?

Comment: You could call have a /config endpoint on the server, which returns the target temperature.  the client calls /config on start up and then periodically to check for updates.

Comment: Can you add code you already have to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use functions

```
#file1
def buzz(config, temp):
    #code
```

```
#file2 (gui)
from file1 import buzz
while True:
    buzz("input from gui", "read temperature from raspberry pi")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get the warning temperature from the server on startup, then do it periodically within your loop, e.g.:

```
update_frequency = 10000
warning_temp = get_config_from_server()
last_update_time = now()

while(true):
    if check_temperature() > warning_temp:
        alarm()
    if now()-last_update_time  > update_frequency:
            warning_temp = get_config_from_server()
            last_update_time  = now()
```